# How to subtract two infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, zeta-functions

While [applying the Sieve of Eratosthenes to Zeta function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02301.pdf) we subtract $\frac{1}{2^s} \zeta(s)$ from $\zeta(s)$ to obtain

$$\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{2^s}\zeta(s) = \sum \frac{1}{n^s} - \sum \frac{1}{(2n)^s}$$

or

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s} \right) \zeta(s) = 1 + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{5^s} + \frac{1}{6^s}+...$$

But when I do the subtraction I don't get the same result.

Since

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^s} - \sum \frac{1}{(2n)^s}$$

is

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{1}{(2n)^s}$$

when I expand this, I get

$$\left(\frac{1}{1^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) + \left(\frac{2^s}{4^s}-\frac{1}{4^s}\right) + \left(\frac{2^s}{6^s}-\frac{1}{6^s}\right)+...$$

or,

$$\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s} + \frac{2^s -1}{4^s} + \frac{2^s-1}{6^s}+...$$

Can you please exlain how I subtract these correctly?

---

First few terms:

```
1        1/2^s       1/3^s       1/4^s
1/2^s    1/4^s       1/6^s       1/8^s
```

Comment: The second sum consists of the even terms of the first one, so only the odd terms are left. Formally, you can rewrite it as:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2n^s}$$

Comment: @LPZ Yes, after subtraction only odd terms are left. But I don't understand how I do the subtraction. I tried subtracting term by term that didn't work either. Can you write explicitly, step by step, how you subtract `(1/2^s) Zeta` from `Zeta`?

Comment: @zeynel The expansion you have is wrong. If you just write first few terms of the two series out, in two separate lines, you'll see how the cancellation works. You're more or less free to manipulate the terms because you know the series converge.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Ok I added first few terms as a table in the question. So, I see 2 fractions e.g., the second terms and I try to subtract them: `1/2^s - 1/4^s` Is this wrong? I don't see any cancellations. Can you tell me what you are cancelling?

Comment: @zeynel write the second row with gaps...

Comment: @ChrisLewis Not sure I understood correctly what you meant by "writing with gaps" but is that what you mean? (I changed the table in the answer)

Comment: @zeynel I don't really know how to give any more hints without just explaining it. Write the terms of the bottom series under their corresponding entries in the first series. All of the even terms cancel. And you're left with the odd ones. That's it! As I say, both series clearly converge, so you don't have to worry about any issues with rearranging or grouping terms as you might with divergent series.

Comment: The first terms are `1` and `1/2^3`. How do they cancel? I see that we struck out even numbered terms. I want to know why this is called "subtraction". Does "subtraction" has another meaning than its usual meaning in the context of infinite series?

Comment: @ChrisLewis Unless we write the two series as $1/1^s - 1/2^s + 1/2^s - 1/4^s + 1/3^s - 1/8^s + 1/4^s - 1/16^s$ Is this what you mean? Are we allowed to write it like this?

Comment: The series $1/2^s + 1/4^s + 1/6^s + \ldots$ is the same as $$0/1^s + 1/2^s + 0/3^s + 1/4^s + 0/5^s + 1/6^s+\ldots$$ as long as the former converges.  Adding in $0$s like this is formally what "with gaps" would mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the question, you have the series

$$\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s} + \frac{2^s -1}{4^s} + \frac{2^s-1}{6^s}+\cdots .$$

This is correct. It is merely not in the form you want.

The general term for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ is

$$ \frac{2^s - 1}{(2n)^s}. $$

Factor this as follows:

$$ \frac{2^s - 1}{(2n)^s} = \frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{n^s}. $$

Now the series can be written like this:

$$ 
\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{1^s} + 
\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{2^s} + 
\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots .
$$

Now you just need to know that if you take a converging series and multiply every single term by the same factor, the sum of the series is multiplied by that same factor.
In this case the converging series is
$\dfrac{1}{1^s} + \dfrac{1}{2^s} + \dfrac{1}{3^s} + \cdots$
and the "same factor" is $\dfrac{2^s - 1}{2^s}.$
Therfore
$$
\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{1^s} + 
\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{2^s} + 
\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\cdot \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots 
= \frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}\left(\frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots \right).
$$

Finally, recognize that
$$\frac{2^s - 1}{2^s}  = 1 - \frac{1}{2^s}$$
so that you can write the result the same way as in the paper.

---

For the part where we want to show that the difference of the two series is equal to the series consisting of only the "odd" terms of $\zeta(s),$
because the series
$\dfrac{2^s - 1}{2^s} + \dfrac{2^s -1}{4^s} + \dfrac{2^s-1}{6^s}+\cdots$
is absolutely convergent,
you can change it to

$$\frac{1}{1^s} - \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} - \frac{1}{4^s}
 + \frac{1}{3^s} - \frac{1}{6^s}+\cdots$$

and then, because it's still absolutely convergent, you can rearrange the order of the terms any way you want, including shifting all the negative terms by increasing number of places to the right so that the sequence of signs is $++-++-++-\cdots$ instead of $+-+-+-+-\cdots.$
That is, it is perfectly OK to write

$$\frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} - \frac{1}{2^s}
 + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} - \frac{1}{4^s}
 + \frac{1}{5^s}+\cdots$$

and so forth. Finally, you can combine the terms three at a time so that
the last two terms in each group of three cancel.

I don't think this would necessarily be OK if it involved any conditionally convergent series, but we have absolute convergence here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This clarifies the multiplication of the series by `1/2^s` to obtain the even-numbered series. But I still don't understand how we obtain Eqn. 3 in the linked paper with only odd numbers. I see that even numbers are struck out but to me that doesn't look like "subtracting".

Comment: When you write "you can write the result the same way as in the paper" I assume that you mean same as Eqn. 3 with only odd numbers. I'm sorry I still don't see how we obtain odd-numbered series by subtracting even numbered series from the original zeta function.

Comment: Do we write the two series like this to subtract: $1/1^s - 1/2^s + 1/2^s - 1/4^s + 1/3^s - 1/8^s + 1/4^s - 1/16^s$ and cancel the even terms?

Comment: Something like that, basically, yes. I've added that part to the answer, since the part I wrote earlier really doesn't explain how the even-numbered terms disappeared.

Comment: Thanks, it all make sense now.